# Use HTML colspan value as variable in CSS?

Tags: html, css, attributes

i have this ugly code:

```
td[colspan="2" ] { width: calc(2  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 2;  }
td[colspan="3" ] { width: calc(3  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 3;  }
td[colspan="4" ] { width: calc(4  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 4;  }
td[colspan="5" ] { width: calc(5  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 5;  }
td[colspan="6" ] { width: calc(6  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 6;  }
td[colspan="7" ] { width: calc(7  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 7;  }
td[colspan="8" ] { width: calc(8  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 8;  }
td[colspan="9" ] { width: calc(9  * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 9;  }
td[colspan="10"] { width: calc(10 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 10; }
td[colspan="11"] { width: calc(11 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 11; }
td[colspan="12"] { width: calc(12 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 12; }
td[colspan="13"] { width: calc(13 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 13; }
td[colspan="14"] { width: calc(14 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 14; }
td[colspan="15"] { width: calc(15 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 15; }
td[colspan="16"] { width: calc(16 * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter 16; }
```

And i want to replace it with nice(r) code like this:

```
td[colspan>1] { width: calc(self.colspan * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter self.colspan; }
```

or

```
td { width: calc(attr(colspan) * 18mm); counter-increment: module_counter attr(colspan); }
```

This example is obviously wrong and invalid. But i hope you get the point.

Is there elegant, portable and future-proof way to do this in pure CSS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: unfortunately match operators for attributes in css selectors, work only on text and can't perform math operations (like >). Maybe there's a way if you used something like sass. Or for sure you could perform a javascript operation to easily select the elements with those condition and perform the style change. By the way afaik it's pretty hard. Since you are just excluding the 0 and 1 options, you could try two different rules `td[colspan=1]` AND `td[colspan]:not([colspan=1])`

Comment: Ok, the `colspan>1` condition is rather optional. But i need to calculate/set the `width` and `counter-increment` properly based on colspan...

Comment: To give you some context of use case, i am working on this label generator: https://raw.githack.com/Harvie/Designs/master/tools/din_rail_module_label_generator.html And i am looking for ways to make the CSS bit more clean and robust.

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly what you asked for. Unfortunately there's no way using css selectors only unless relying on a preprocessor like sass. But this could be a solution using JQuery that would achieve your expectations anyway. But yet not css like you asked:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Example Colspan:2</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Example Colspan:3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready( ()=>{
            $('td').each(
                (i, td)=> {
                    let colspan = $(td).attr('colspan');
                    if( colspan ){
                        $(td).css('width', `calc(${colspan} * 18mm)`);
                        $(td).css('counter-increment', `module_counter ${colspan}`);
                    }
                }
            )
    });
</script>
```